# works in jsfiddle but not in live wordpress site (already added onload function)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I noticed a similar question has been asked before, but i tried the solution suggested which is wrapping my code in an onload function which is what jsfiddle does, but its still not working for me. Heres the jsfiddle, i copied identical html from the live site and everything works perfect

http://jsfiddle.net/pxJHc/40/

its a plus minus function for my woocomerce site which stopped working after i ran the latest update. Pretty straight forward

```
$('.minus, .plus').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var $input = $(this).siblings('.qty');
    var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
    $input.val(val + ($(this).hasClass('minus') ? -1 : 1));
});
```

i added

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //put the javascript from the jsfiddle in here
});
```

like some previous answers on here suggested but still nothing. Heres the live site

http://tinyurl.com/p4s7k5t

im not getting any errors in the console, everything seems to be working fine. But nothing happens when i click plus or minus.... any ideas?

thanks

Comment: When i check external website, i get error in console. Now try: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});`

Comment: You are getting no errors in your console ? Please check this again: `TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: I am getting $ = undefined in the console, but jQuery = 
jquery.js?ver=1.11.1:2 function (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)}, so try changing $ for jQuery in your code.

Comment: Exactly in which browser are you not seeing the console errors? Are you opening the console after you load the page?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress loads jQuery in noconflict mode, which means that jQuery is not set to the `$` variable automatically. You can read about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   //put the javascript from the jsfiddle in here
});
```

So you will be able to use $ inside your load function.

If not you have to change $ to jQuery.